Dominating function for $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 \frac{n+n^kx^k}{(1+\sqrt{x})^n}$

Compute $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 \frac{n+n^kx^k}{(1+\sqrt{x})^n}$, where $k \geq 1$.

Letting $f_n(x) := \frac{n+n^kx^k}{(1+\sqrt{x})^n} $, we have the pointwise limit $f_n \rightarrow 0$ a.e. . To see this, consider the first term, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{(1+\sqrt{x})^n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\log(1+\sqrt{x})(1+\sqrt{x})^{n}} = 0$ by L'Hopital, for $x \in (0,1)$. We can show similarly for the second term $\frac{n^kx^k}{(1+\sqrt{x})^n}$.
However, I am unable to find an integrable dominating function for the first term, $\frac{n}{(1+\sqrt{x})^n}$. By simulation, however, it seems like $\int_0^1 \frac{n}{(1+\sqrt{x})^n} \rightarrow 0$, and moreover that it is dominated by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, but I'm unable to show it.
I'd also appreciate learning any general strategies for finding bounds that can be specialized for this question. I'm guessing a lot of it is trial and error, but my trouble is that all I'm able to use is that $(1+u)^a \geq 1+u^a$ for the above case, which only yields $\frac{n}{(1+\sqrt{x})^n} \leq \frac{n}{1+x^{n/2}}$, and from where I am unable to see how to proceed.

$(1+x)^n\geqslant1+nx$ - it follows from $(1+x)^n\big|{x=0}=(1+nx)\big|{x=0} (=1)$ and $\frac d{dx}(1+x)^n=n(1+x)^{n-1}>n=\frac d{dx}(1+nx)$ at $x\in[0;1]$
$$\Rightarrow,,\frac n{(1+\sqrt x)^n}\leqslant\frac n{1+n\sqrt x}<\frac1{\sqrt x}$$


However, I am unable to find an integrable dominating function for the first term, $\frac{n}{(1+\sqrt{x})^n}$. By simulation, however, it seems like $\int_0^1 \frac{n}{(1+\sqrt{x})^n} \rightarrow 0$, and moreover that it is dominated by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, but I'm unable to show it.

By the binomial theorem,
$$\begin{align*}
(1 + \sqrt x)^n
&= \sum_{m=0}^n \binom n m x^{m/2}\\
&= n \sqrt x + \sum_{\substack{0 \le m \le n \\ m \ne 1}} \binom n m x^{m/2}\\
&= n \sqrt x + \underbrace{1+\binom n 1 x^{1/2} + \binom n 2 x + \cdots + \binom n m x^{m/2} +\cdots x^{n/2}}_{\text{all positive terms since $x \in (0,1)$}} \\
&\ge n\sqrt x
\end{align*}$$
so
$$
\frac{n}{(1+\sqrt x)^n} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt x}
$$
as desired.


I'd also appreciate learning any general strategies for finding bounds that can be specialized for this question. I'm guessing a lot of it is trial and error [...]

Yeah that's the gist I've gotten in my experience. I've been helped by having a list of inequalities and Taylor series in my notes, and trying to remember or have on-hand past such dominations I've proved before if they used an unusual technique.
